ServiceStack OpenAPI Swagger Exclude "auth" methods
How can I exclude these base "auth" methods circled in the screenshot from my ServiceStack application's Swagger docs?


In OpenAPI v3 they can be removed with a Swashbuckle DocumentFilter you can register where you enable Swagger:
services.AddSwaggerGen(c => {
    c.DocumentFilter<OpenApiDocumentFilter>();
});

Where the Document Filter removes all the paths you don't want:
public class OpenApiDocumentFilter(OpenApiMetadata metadata) : IDocumentFilter
{
    public void Apply(OpenApiDocument doc, DocumentFilterContext context)
    {
        doc.Paths.Remove("/auth");
        doc.Paths.Remove("/auth/{provider}");
        doc.Paths.Remove("/assignroles");
        doc.Paths.Remove("/unassignroles");
    }
}

In Open API v2 they can be removed with an ApiDeclarationFilter, e.g:
Plugins.Add(new OpenApiFeature
{
    ApiDeclarationFilter = doc => {
        doc.Paths.Remove("/auth");
        doc.Paths.Remove("/auth/{provider}");
        doc.Paths.Remove("/assignroles");
        doc.Paths.Remove("/unassignroles");
    }
});


Can I +1 you for answering for both OpenAPI v3 AND OpenAPI v2!
